# Cannot use Vue-Router to get the parameters in the URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Today, when trying to use Vue-Router (in Vue-CLI) to get URL parameters, I encountered difficulties ($route.query is empty), the code is as follows.

Code purpose: Get the parameters carried after the URL (such as client_id in "http://localhost:8080/#/?client_id=00000000000077")

Project file structure:[image]

router/index.js:[image]

App.vue(Get part of the code for URL parameters):[image]

The running result of this part of the code:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `$router.currentRoute` and `$route` aren't matching up, but you could simply use `$router.currentRoute.query.client_id` if you need it in `mounted()`.

Another workaround is to use a [`$watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#watch) on `$route.query.client_id`:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const unwatch = this.$watch('$route.query.client_id', clientId => {
      console.log({ clientId })

      // no need to continue watching
      unwatch()
    })
  }
}
```

Or [`watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch) in the Composition API:

```js
import { watch } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log({
      route: this.$route,
      router: this.$router,
    })
  },
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()

    const unwatch = watch(() => route.query.client_id, clientId => {
      console.log({ clientId })

      // no need to continue watching
      unwatch()
    })
  }
}
```